# Redirection Htaccess without a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all URL having a trailing slash referenced by google to the new url without a trailing slash.

Example : 
http://example.com/toto/ ===> to http://example.com/toto

Warning I already rewrite the rule to avoid the .html extension also !

Here is my existing code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I got the following error :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /example/.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

The objectif of the topic was to find a solution to make a redirection of existing URL listed by search engine like google to not lose the current SEO after making a complete refresh of the web site (Wordpress to bootstrap).

The first objective was to redirect all url trafics like http://example.com/toto/ (google) ===> to http://example.com/toto.

Unfortunatly I understood that making the reverse is more powerful to not lose my existing listing on google (sitemap & robots)

So I have decided to review all the code in order to have the following result by deleting the html extension and adding a trailing slash at the end of each url :

http://example.com/toto.html ===> to http://example.com/toto ==> http://example.com/toto/

Below is the code HTaccess that I used to make this possible :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash at the end  /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# delete the extension .html 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

I have also added the code line below in each html page to enforce it :

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Hoping to help any readers/coders in the same situation